# How can get certain field value from dataSource in kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have defined dataSource like this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    {Id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", description: "some description", numberValue: "3000.00" },
    {Id: 2, name: "John Connor", description: "description temp", numberValue: "1800.00" },
    {Id: 3, name: "T-100", description: "descr tmp", numberValue: "2200.00"}
  ],
  schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                name: { type: "string" },
                description: { type: "string" },
                numberValue: { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get certain field value from dataSource? 
For example: I want get value for field numberValue (where Id = 1, or Id = 2 or Id = 3). 
If I call dataSource.data.numberValue then nothing happening. Any help really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

dataSource.data is an array obviously.

Comment: That's for sure. But, how can i get concrete value of field from dataSource? For example: I want to know value of field `numberValue` in array, where Id = 2. Or, I want to know value of field `name` in array, where Id = 3.

Comment: There is no query syntax in kendo lib AFAIK. You would have to loop trough data to locate your record.

Comment: `for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n: i++) { var item = data[i]; if (item.Id===2) alert('Hooray!'); }`